# Use foreach to return multiple different dataframes

Tags: r, foreach

I have a foreach loop that runs multiple functions, each of which produces a unique dataframe featuring partially different column names and a different amount of columns. I want to adapt the foreach loop in a way that it runs the loop, and returns me two dataframes, each containing an rbind() version of all iterations produced by one function (i.e. one dataframe for function1 and one dataframe for function2.

My best attempt so far only produces the dataframe consisting of rbind() iterations of the first function. Please find the code below:

Expected output:
One dataframe with the results produced by function1() pasted in a dataframe with 10 rows (1 per iteration) and a second dataframe produced with the results produced by function2().

Note: In my actual work, I´m doing permutations. Therefore, the two functions must be used in the same loop, and cannot be used in two distinct loops.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(foreach, doParallel, gtools)


#make a dataframe
participant <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
group <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
latency <- c(1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.3, 1.7, 2.2, 2.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(participant, group, latency))

#does some stuff
function1 <- function(){
  ttest <- t.test(latency ~ group, data = data, paired = FALSE)
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ttest$statistic,ttest$p.value))
  return(df)
}
#does some different stuff
function2 <- function(){
  ttest <- t.test(latency ~ group, data = data, paired = FALSE)
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ttest$statistic, ttest$p.value, ttest$conf.int))
  return(df)
}

#both produce differently sized dataframes
df <- function1()
df2 <- function2()


#set up  repetitions
permutation <- 1:10

#set up the dopar version
#number of cores
n_cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1

# This part you always need, you can delete the outfile = "mylog.txt" part later, but its good for debugging. All output from the dopar part will go into that file, you can open it in rstudio to see it in real time (see the cat1, cat2 print)
cl <- makeCluster(rep("localhost", n_cores), outfile="mylog.txt")


# this function will be exported to the workers and will do nothing but evaluate library("packagename") for each package.
export_packages <- function(package_list){
  for(pac in package_list){
    eval(bquote(library(.(pac))))
    
  }
}
# this is a list/collection of all packages
package_list <- (.packages())
# now we export the entire global environment including the list of the packages that are loaded+ the function to load them on the workers
clusterExport(cl, as.list(names(as.list(.GlobalEnv))))
# instead of directly writing library("packagename") here as above, we just tell the workers to each evaluate the export_packages function with the package_list that have been exported to the workers
clusterEvalQ(cl, c(export_packages(package_list)))
# note that we delete the registerDoParalel in line 7 and instead only specify n_cores there
registerDoParallel(cl)


#Note: This code only saves the first dataframe created, not the second.
#I want to save both dataframes to the list, and then create 2 final dataframes, each containing only the output of one function.
system.time({
  dataframe <- foreach(i = permutation) %dopar% {
    
        #run multiverse
    
    
    df <- function1()
    #count itereations
    count <- i
    
    #save as dataset
    df_prelim <- as.data.frame(cbind(df, count))
    return(df_prelim)
    
    
    #second output dataset
    df2 <- function2()
    df2_prelim <- as.data.frame(cbind(df2, count))
    return(df_prelim2)
    
  }
  #turn list to dataframe.
  #this should return two dataframes
  df_final<- ldply(dataframe, data.frame)
})


stopCluster(cl)
```